# How to set finger touch functionality in android?

Tags: android, swap, zooming

I am developing a small application in android in which i have few image in my application i want when user touch with one finger images can move left or right side and when user can touch with two fingers it could be zoom how can i do this please refer some tutorial code for me.
here is my code 
and i used view flipper in xml v fdjf

```
public class Jaap extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

float downXValue;
int counter = 0;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

// Set main.XML as the layout for this Activity
setContentView(R.layout.jaap);

// Add these two lines
LinearLayout layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
layMain.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this); 

// Add a few countries to the spinner

}

public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

// Get the action that was done on this touch event
switch (arg1.getAction())
{
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
{
// store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
downXValue = arg1.getX();
break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
{
// Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
float currentX = arg1.getX(); 

// going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
if (downXValue < currentX)
{
// Get a reference to the ViewFlipper
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
// Set the animation
// vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out));
// Flip!
if(counter > 0){
vf.showPrevious();
counter--;
}
}
// going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
if (downXValue > currentX)
{
// Get a reference to the ViewFlipper
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
// Set the animation
// vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_in));
// Flip!
if(counter < 131){
vf.showNext();
counter++;
}
}
break;
}
}

// if you return false, these actions will not be recorded
return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the MotionEvent in the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) of the Activity.
In this check for the MotionEvent.getAction().

```
switch(MotionEvent.GetAction()) {
case ACTION_DOWN:
//handle the finger down functionality here
break;

case ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
//handle the second finger down functionality here
break;
}
```

A sequence of events would be issued, mostly with the actions as follows:

- ACTION_DOWN  - one finger touch down
- ACTION_MOVE   -> the finger is moved
- ACTION_UP - one finger touch is removed
- ACTION_POINTER_DOWN - second finger touch down
- ACTION_POINTER_UP - second finger touch up

You will have to check the X,Y positions in the event and determine what should be donw...
will see if there are any good tutorials/samples to explain these better...

Comment: i tried to implement this code but there is a problem that if the image get zoomed and i drag it also but i can't move to next image

Comment: @Avi, yes I have seen such a functionality in some of the phones also. When the image is zoomed, the drag (or flick) does not move to next image. Only after the image is restored to the original size then the flick works. /n Can you please let us know where is the enlarged image getting drawn? And in this situation, where is the touch event coming and how is it handled?...there could be a possibility that when the image is zoomed the drag (or flick) is being ignored...

Comment: have a placed my code in my quetion have look at it look at my code

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=mantle_skin;content) step-by-step tutorial, it contains code examples how to zoom in/out a picture and move it around.

Answer (score 1):

`getPointerCount()` of `motionEvent` tells you how many fingers are touch. In gives number of touch

Thanks